# How to set dynamic datatype based on field value for associated model sunspot solr

Tags: sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

We have implementing custom fields feature one of our application.

Currently we store table name 'abc' data inside sunspot solr.

Now we have added one table custom fields which is has many relation with 'abc' table.

We store custom field data with multiple data types. like date, string, boolean etc.

Write now we are string dynamic field data using dynamic_string type.

below is the ruby code example.

searchble do
dynamic_string :custom_field, stored: true do
custom_fields.inject({}) do |hash, custom_field|
hash.merge((custom_field.key) => custom_field.value)
end
end
end

But we want to define dynamic datatype based on type of custom field.

like
if string type data it wil be dynamic string, date data type it will we dynamic_date etc